# Android studio gradle build error 'after' connecting it to firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

after connecting to firebase realtime database , I am getting build gradle error as :-
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPuqb.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/evv5S.png)

I tried changing gradle plugin versions but errror is not getting solved

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Can you please recheck your google json and gradle module level

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur Please check json file provided by firebase. Make a try with remove the current json file from project, download new json file from firebase and add that file to project again.

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur could you tell where i will find that json file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.